# Encapsulate sub-group of methods of a class inside a typed named object

Tags: dart

I would like to encapsulate a sub-group of methods within a class, giving the encapsulation a name of "helperFunctions", and be typed. For example, I want to call the helper functions like this:

```
myClassInstance.helperFunctions.someHelperFunction(AnyParamsYouLike params);
```

The effect that I want is to have this class add a named typed wrapper around its helper functions, as a form of documentation so that I can remove the comment:

```
SomeClass extends VpCubit<LoggedOutNickNameState, MyHelperFunctionsType> {

  // helper functions
  void onSubmitPressed(BuildContext context) {
    saveNickNameLocallyUseCase
        .invoke(form.control(nickNameKey).value as String ?? '');

    Navigator.pushNamed(context, Routes.LOGGED_OUT_EMAIL,
            arguments: LoggedOutEmailPageArgs(
                form.control(nickNameKey).value as String ?? ''))
        .then((value) => initialise());
  }

}
```

The base class will enforce the property "helperFunctions" exists (and is nullable) on subclasses and will let the subclasses define the Type of the HelperFunctions object (which will specify the function names). It will look something like this, however, not like this as it doesn't work, that is what my question is about, how to properly implement this:

```
class VpCubit<T, SpecificTypeWithAnyFunctions> extends Cubit<T> {
  VpCubit(T initial) : super(initial) {
    if (onCreate != null) {
      onCreate();
    }
  }

  void onClose() => print('');
  void onCreate() => print('');

  @override
  Future<void> close() async {
    if (onClose != null) {
      onClose();
    }

    return super.close();
  }

  HelperFunctions<SpecificTypeWithAnyFunctions> helperFunctions;
}

class HelperFunctions<SpecificTypeWithAnyFunctions> {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```dart
abstract class VpCubit<T, H extends HelperFunctions> extends Cubit<T> {
  // ...
  H? get helperFunctions;
}
abstract class HelperFunctions { 
  // Anything shared by all helper function objects.
}

class SomeClass extends VpCubit<int, SomeHelpers> {
  int get whatnot => 42;
  late final SomeHelpers? helperFunctions = SomeHelpers._(this);
}
class SomeHelpers extends HelperFunctions {
  final SomeClass _self;
  SomeHelpers._(this._self);
  int someHelperFunction() => _self.whatnot + 5;
}
```

This puts a `helperFunctions` getter (nullable as requested) on every instance of `VpCubit`, of a type specified by the subtype.

Answer (score 0):

So far the best I have is to create a new class per VpCubit extension that accepts the params required for its functions:

```
class LoggedOutNickNameHelperFunctions extends HelperFunctions {
  LoggedOutNickNameHelperFunctions(
      this.saveNickNameLocallyUseCase, this.form, this.nickNameKey, this.state);

  void onSubmitPressed(BuildContext context) {
    saveNickNameLocallyUseCase
        .invoke(form.control(nickNameKey).value as String ?? '');

    Navigator.pushNamed(context, Routes.LOGGED_OUT_EMAIL,
            arguments: LoggedOutEmailPageArgs(
                form.control(nickNameKey).value as String ?? ''))
        .then<dynamic>((value) => state);
  }

  final SaveNickNameLocallyUseCase saveNickNameLocallyUseCase;
  final FormGroup form;
  final String nickNameKey;
  final LoggedOutNickNameState state;
}
```

And then add a getter to return it from the VpCubit extension:

```
  @override
  LoggedOutNickNameHelperFunctions get helperFunctions => _helperFunctions;
```

Setting the _helperFunctions instance in the constructor:

```
_helperFunctions = LoggedOutNickNameHelperFunctions(
          saveNickNameLocallyUseCase, form, nickNameKey, state);
```

It is a shame this is not all nested within the class itself but nested classes are not allowed in Dart. Keen to see if there is a more succinct way.